# Ant + JUnit: How to define VM for Junit?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have code compiled with 1.5 and also libraries that cannot cope with 1.6. So how can I run Junit tests for this? (I have the latest JUnit version that runs with the system JVM 1.6 default) I assume something with forking and JVM args but found no exact clues...

Answer (score 2):

Just download and install a java 1.5 jvm and use that. For ant, you can specify the jvm to use by using the `jvm` parameter, but you'll need to specify `fork=true` as well.

See [Ant: JUnit Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: At the JVM parameter I can define the Java command according to the doc - can you provide an example? Because I don't want to specify commands to system speicifc paths (i.e. JDK). I assume that I will have to check in the JDK as well to our versioning system so that it can run also on our build server (which has other paths than development machines)...